# Debugging Android application on BlackBerry PlayBook

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook

I am trying to run an Android application on a BlackBerry PlayBook Simulator using the Eclipse plug-in but the problem I am facing is that the simulator cannot connect to the ADB. I registered for the BlackBerry signing keys, set the PlayBook to Development Mode, added a BlackBerry nature to the project, configured the application's target, and even validated the app's compatibility using the online tool (I'd much rather use the Eclipse plug-in instead so that I can test my app before publishing, whereas the online tool I believe requires you to publish before you get to test). Below is the error log that is displayed onto my console.

```
[2011-11-10 11:22:37 - HelloAndroid] Packaging project HelloAndroid
[2011-11-10 11:22:40 - HelloAndroid] Launching BlackBerry Android Runtime...
[2011-11-10 11:22:53 - HelloAndroid] Connecting to ADB...
[2011-11-10 11:22:54 - BlackBerry] unable to connect to 192.168.49.128:5555
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, it seems that I wasn't using the simulator for Tablet OS 2.0. Now I am able to run Android applications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to debug android apps directly on the Playbook by using the following steps to run unsigned apps -

https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/android/documentation/load_an_unsigned_app_onto_a_pb_1767302_11.html

Answer (score 0):

It's not that AT ALL.. It's just mean eclipse still use the old all target (192.168.49.128). So you need just to change it - to do that :

- Into Run Configuration (look the green and white play button and click on the little arrow on the right -> "Run Configuration")
- into 'BlackBerry Android Application' -> click on the name of your APP
- Click on the tab "Traget"
- Select the device you want eclipse launch the app (in my case I have "172.16.153.128" and "172.16.153.130")